# pathspec 'feature_branch' did not match any files(s) known to git

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules, cicd

Gitlab cicd with submodule, I try checkout a specific branch from the submodule it errors **"pathspec "feature_branch" did  not match any file(s) known to git"**

the directory structure is like below

[image]

I am trying to checkout a specific branch from the dev1 repo with the following command

- cd dev1
- git checkout $feature_branch

But when i do check with `git branch` command it only shows main. when I use `git ls-remote` then its showing all the branches.

Comment: what is the name of the branch you are trying to check out? Is it setup in the `$feature_branch` variable correctly?

Comment: yes i tried hardcode also same error..

Comment: I think we need to know what is the _exact_ git command that is being run so that we can tell you what the best course of action should be.

Comment: 1. ```git submodule init``` 2. ```git submodule update``` 3. ```pushd dev``` 4. ```git feature_branch```

Comment: can you elaborate on step 4 (which is where I guess it is breaking, right)? I do not think that `git feature_branch` will fly if I try to run it.

Comment: I got a solution, the issue is, i was trying to fetch the remote branch which is already in my local.